# How to prevent DNN Skin AddModule Message from auto-scrolling the page?

Tags: scroll, dotnetnuke, dnn9

The DNN **DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage** method causes the page to auto scroll on Postback. I am using DNN 9.01.01

**I did try MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack**, but it seems like you can't use this in a Master page: 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1038248.aspx?MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack+true+IN+MASTER

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

This is the method that is causing the trouble in DNN:

```
private void AddModuleMessage(ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType moduleMsgType, string Message, bool error = true)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            moduleMsgType = ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError;
        }

        DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(plcMessages, Message, moduleMsgType);
    }
```

I have tried to disable Focus() on inputs, but it does the same.
Here are other sources I looked at https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/284691/scope/posts/when-page-loaded-the-browser-scrolls-down

Also, does Update Panels cause auto scrolling?